# Query Returning One Row in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

When I run the following query, I only get the first row:

```
SELECT 
u.name AS Firstname, u.lastname AS Lastname, count( DISTINCT(p.id) ) AS Count
FROM
projects p
INNER JOIN users u ON p.user_fk = u.id
order by user_fk;
```

I have two tables, Projects and Users and the project table has a user ID which I am using to get the name from the users table. I then want to see how many unique projects there are for each user and display the amount of projects each user has.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a `group by`:

```
SELECT u.name AS Firstname, u.lastname AS Lastname,
       count( DISTINCT p.id ) AS Count
FROM projects p INNER JOIN
     users u
     ON p.user_fk = u.id
GROUP BY u.name, u.lastname
order by user_fk;
```

In almost any other database, your query would return an error, because it has columns in the `SELECT` that are not aggregated and not in the `GROUP BY`.  I think MySQL is moving toward making that the default behavior.